# Pull out numbers from a mixture of numbers + string of words

Tags: python

I need to pull out specific numbers from a text file that has a combination of numbers and text strings. The text file looks like this:

```
# General info User: b_stone, time: Sat Oct 21 16:10:03 2017 # Temperature C # Counters sec=60, Monitor=2.28666e+07, bstop=5.63852e+06, I0=7.33642e+06, I1=0, ch5=0, ch6=0, ch7=0, TEMP=-1, ICRxT=1, OCRxT=1, ROI1=1, ROI2=1, ROI3=1, ROI4=1, ROI5=1, ROI6=1, ccd1=0 # Motors goniy=40.7889, samplez=150, phi=-15.2418, th=0, detx=20.75, dety=4.7, detz=200, platz=0, m8=0, m9=0, m10=0, m11=0, dethorz=-5.10603, detvert=-31.6, detzold=879.936, m15=0, t1v=0, b1v=0, l1h=0, r1h=0, t2v=1.15812, b2v=-1.00813, l2h=1.24, r2h=-0.94, gshorz=4.50913, gsvert=0, stagey=-967.21, stagex=-102.567, bsvert=0, bshorz=0.24, samplex=-8, sampley=2.22, bpm=10090, monbend=330, monslit=9.29845, monang=-12, m0pitch=4.24658, m0vert=1.3622, m0bend=19.4294, m39=189.405, tablev1=39.7621, tablev2=59.9162, thor=1.09867, tableya=1.2001, bsv=24.3409, bsh=2.005, stagex1=1.95228, stagey1=3.07772, h1gap=0, h1tran=0, v1gap=0, v1tran=0, h2gap=0.3, h2tran=-1.09, v2gap=0.15, v2tran=1.0831, table=49.8391, tablep=0.01167, tempset=25
```

What I'd like to do is to look at "Monitor=2.28666e+07" (see the second line in the big string of texts) and just pull out "2.28666".

I knew how to do this in matlab, but I don't know how to convert the code to python.

This is the matlab code that used to work

```
%Extract the monitor value from .txt file generated
k=sprintf('txt_files/MnO2_20170515_2_05151339_%04d.txt',i);    
filetext=fileread(k);
numbers = str2double(regexp(filetext, '(?<=Monitor=[^0-9]*)[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+', 'match'));
MV = numbers; %Monitor value, I scale up the MV by 10^6
%save monitor values into vector m 
m(i)=MV;
```

I want to do the same thing in python, and expect the output to be 2.28666.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python provided for you `re` as a standard regex lib, you can try this code for your problem.

```py
>>>import re
>>>s = 'General info User: b_stone, time: Sat Oct 21 16:10:03 2017 # Temperature C # Counters sec=60, Monitor=2.28666e+07, bstop=5.63852e+06, I0=7.33642e+06, I1=0, ch5=0, ch6=0, ch7=0, TEMP=-1, ICRxT=1, OCRxT=1, ROI1=1, ROI2=1, ROI3=1, ROI4=1, ROI5=1, ROI6=1, ccd1=0 # Motors goniy=40.7889, samplez=150, phi=-15.2418, th=0, detx=20.75, dety=4.7, detz=200, platz=0, m8=0, m9=0, m10=0, m11=0, dethorz=-5.10603, detvert=-31.6, detzold=879.936, m15=0, t1v=0, b1v=0, l1h=0, r1h=0, t2v=1.15812, b2v=-1.00813, l2h=1.24, r2h=-0.94, gshorz=4.50913, gsvert=0, stagey=-967.21, stagex=-102.567, bsvert=0, bshorz=0.24, samplex=-8, sampley=2.22, bpm=10090, monbend=330, monslit=9.29845, monang=-12, m0pitch=4.24658, m0vert=1.3622, m0bend=19.4294, m39=189.405, tablev1=39.7621, tablev2=59.9162, thor=1.09867, tableya=1.2001, bsv=24.3409, bsh=2.005, stagex1=1.95228, stagey1=3.07772, h1gap=0, h1tran=0, v1gap=0, v1tran=0, h2gap=0.3, h2tran=-1.09, v2gap=0.15, v2tran=1.0831, table=49.8391, tablep=0.01167, tempset=25'
>>>a = re.findall(r'Monitor=(\d.\d+)', s)
>>>a
['2.28666']
>>>a[0]
'2.28666'
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

with open('KMnOx_1Macid_1020_0630pm_10201916_0001.txt', "r") as F:
    readDat =F.read()

    parsedData =re.findall(r"Monitor=([+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+))", readDat) %read the whole number including e+07
    parsedData =re.findall(r"Monitor=(\d.\d+)", readDat) %read the number except e+07

    monitorCount = float(parsedData[0])


print(monitorCount)
```

Based on Lê Tư Thành's suggestion..
I tried this code and it worked out :)

Comment: If your problem was solved, please mark it as fixed to save time for other guys.